# How to share component between React apps in single repository

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have spent hours looking for the simplest possible standalone solution for this, but to no avail. I have found some half-answered SO questions that do not seem to apply here. My question:

I have two create-react-app apps in the same GitHub repository. I want to share some components between them, let's say in a `shared` folder in the same root dir as the two react apps. When I use `npm link`, or do e.g. `mkdir shared; cd shared; npm init; cd ../app1; npm install ../shared`, it resolves the path just fine when I do `import MyComponent from "shared";`, but gives me an error:

```
../shared/index.js
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/dev/frontends/shared/index.js: Unexpected token (7:6)
```

If I understand correctly, this just means that my code is not comp/transpiled, but I don't know how to fix it. I can't for the life of me understand why React makes it so hard to share code locally between apps. I am looking for the simplest possible local solution, that does not involve having a separate repository for this package (via github or npm or bit or whatever). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error that you are getting, it seems that your JSX code is not getting compiled. When you do something like `import MyComponent from "shared"`, react-scripts does not compile `MyComponent` to es5. It only compiles files which are under the scope of that project, i.e. `src/`. So to use it like the way you are doing, you can export transpiled react components from package1 and then import it in package2.

You can also give monorepo a shot. Probably it goes with your requirement. Check out [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna).